# How to add parity bits for a checksum when dealing with strings

Tags: c, checksum

So I have this Checksum function shown below that I need to implement in some code I am working on. I am still at a novice level with a lot of this stuff and was hoping someone could enlighten me on how to work with it.

I am in a situation where I need to pass in an array that has an odd number of characters. Obviously this checksum won't allow for that to happen so I was wondering if there was a way to add a character to the array so that its length becomes even but the character itself won't affect the sum. I do know about parity bits, but in this case I am not passing in a binary number but rather a string of characters.

Also I am not able to modify any of the checksum code, I only have control over what I pass into it i.e buf and length.

Any help would be much appreciated

Cheers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


unsigned short checksum(unsigned char buf[], int length)
{
    int i;
    unsigned short word16;
    unsigned int sum32;

    if (length % 2) // if odd
        return 999;

    sum32 = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i = i + 2) {
        word16 = (buf[i] << 8) + buf[i+1];
        sum32 = sum32 + word16;
        if (sum32 & 0x10000)
            sum32 = (sum32 & 0xffff) + 1;
    }

    sum32 = ~sum32;
    
    return (sum32 & 0xffff);
}
```

Declaration of buf

```
buf[0] = '0';
buf[1] = '1';
buf[2] = '2';
buf[3] = '3';
buf[4] = '4';
buf[5] = '5';
buf[6] = '6';
buf[7] = '7';
buf[8] = '8';
buf[9] = '9';

checksum(buf,10);
```

Comment: `if there was a way to add a character to the array` No it's not possible. Would be easier if you would show how do you _call_ the function `checksum`, as this is the code you can change.

Comment: I call it by doing checksum(buf, length).

buf in one case is a string "0123456789" and length is the length of that so 10 in this case(not counting the null character). The issue is when I need to add a zero at the start of that string because of the way the checksum works, I am now at 11 characters which doesn't work

Comment: Edit your post and add additional detail there. Please show actual code. What is `buf`? What is `length`? Specifically, how is memory allocated for `buf`? Why not use zero terminating character as a +1 in case of an odd string length?

Comment: It would be very difficult to show all of my code but I will try to add more details about  how buf is declared, in terms of the zero terminating character, how would that work exactly? I have stumbled upon that but didn't know how to implement it.

Comment: `length = strlen(buf) + (strlen(buf) % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 1)`... Please create an [MCVE]. `Declaration of buf` that's not a [declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/declarations).

Comment: There's nowhere in the code where it declares buf as "unsigned char buf[10];". What I gave above was the first time buf is used and passed in the code. It will take me a while but I can try to make a reproducible example.Its a bit tricky because the code relies on pre built functions(which I did not make) that are being passed around. I will try to see what I can do

Answer (score 0):

As you checksum code is computing a 16 bit sum of each pair of bytes
your input has, there is no way to add a byte to the buffer that will not
alter the sum. You could add two '\x00' bytes to an even buffer and it
will not affect the sum.

But if you want to have checksums of any kind of string (odd or even)
you could copy the buffer of odd strings into even buffers and padd with
0 at the end, and compute the checksum with the resulting even length.
In that case you will not have collitions between the checksums of the
odds and the evens (not because of this matter) because even
strings will not have '\x00' at end.

Concept example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned short checksum(unsigned char buf[], int length)
{
    int i;
    unsigned short word16;
    unsigned int sum32;

    if (length % 2) // if odd
        return 999;

    sum32 = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i = i + 2) {
        word16 = (buf[i] << 8) + buf[i+1];
        sum32 = sum32 + word16;
        if (sum32 & 0x10000)
            sum32 = (sum32 & 0xffff) + 1;
    }

    sum32 = ~sum32;
    
    return (sum32 & 0xffff);
}

int main()
{
    char testOdd[]="Odd";
    char testEven[]="Even";
    char testBuffer[5];
    
    unsigned short chkodd,chkeven;
    
    memcpy(testBuffer,testEven,4);
    testBuffer[4]=0;
    chkeven=checksum(testBuffer,strlen(testBuffer));
    memcpy(testBuffer,testOdd,3);
    testBuffer[3]=0;
    testBuffer[4]=0; // just to be clear
    chkodd=checksum(testBuffer,strlen(testBuffer)+1);
    
    printf("Checksum for Odd: %d, Checksum for Even: %d\r\n",chkodd,chkeven);
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Thank You This is pretty helpful

Comment: One question that I have speaking a bit more generally, how do we know if a string such as "Hello World" can be divided into 16 bit words?

Comment: I have another question about ur code. Say the strings "Even" and "Odd" were sent to a server along with their checksums. How would the server be able to use those 2 pieces of information to figure out whether there was data lost or corrupted during transmission?

Comment: 1- if it is even you can divided into 16 bitwords (2 bytes). 
2- The server must calculate the checksum itself and compare it with the incoming one.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. So if I understand, the server would take only the message part, send that through the checksum algorithm and then if it is equal to the checksum that it was sent then it knows everything is good with that transmission, is that right?

Comment: that is the idea, of course false positives could occur, and that is why certain checksums are stronger than others depending on the situation.